# simple_oauth refresh token works only one time

Tags: authentication-authorization

I use the **[simple_oauth][1]** module to authenticate the user.

I have generated the first **access_token** using the **grant_type=password**.

then I have tried to get a new **access_token** using my **refresh_token** received from first request :

```
POST /oauth/token

grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:def50200d3c74fa2e41a886a6ff1...
client_secret:l0r3m1psum
```

the first time I execute the request it returns the new **access_token** :

```
{
    "token_type": "Bearer",
    "expires_in": 300,
    "access_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJS..",
    "refresh_token": "def502002b9ce17870bc285427a6.."
}
```

the problem is the second time I run the same request it Doesn't works and I get **401 unauthorized** with this HTML body :

```
{
    "error": "invalid_request",
    "error_description": "The refresh token is invalid.",
    "hint": "Token has been revoked",
    "message": "The refresh token is invalid."
}
```

for the second request I have used the same **refresh_token**(I'am sure it not expired I have set ttl to 78000 for test) :

```
POST /oauth/token

grant_type:refresh_token
refresh_token:def50200d3c74fa2e41a886a6ff1...
client_secret:l0r3m1psum
```

**grant_type:refresh_token** request will enable us to get new access_token as long as refresh token not expired?

but it is like getting expires after just executing a request one time , if I generate a new **refresh_token** using the   **grant_type:password** in my case the **grant_type:refresh_token** request works fine .

but in
[1]: https://www.drupal.org/project/simple_oauth

Comment: Please show the second request. Did you use the new access token in the second request?

Comment: I think this is the way refresh tokens work. You use them once.

Comment: As far as I know, Cliefen is correct. When you use the refresh token, it is expired, and you receive a new refresh token together with the new authorization token you requested.

Comment: @cilefen have added the second request to the question, and about using the refresh token once

Comment: @Jaypan but this refresh token has not expired yet , it is like it is expired directly after the first equest

Answer (score 1):

This is working as expected. You receive a new access token and refresh token. You must use those in subsequent requests.

Comment: Cliefen is correct. Your first request to `/oauth/token` with the refresh token returned a NEW token. You need to replace the old token with the new token for the next request. Then when that next request is made, you will receive a NEW Oauth token, and replace the last one, and then you repeat forever.

Comment: Actually the access token is usable during the expires_in time.

Comment: Good point. My post should have made it clear that the requests being referred to were only requests to the `/oauth/token` endpoint for `grant_type=refresh_token`, and not requests made to other endpoints.